Why image and category text have line break when I add link tag?
I am working on a Laravel site using Tailwind CSS. I have a small of block with image and text, like:
<div
    class="mb-1 flex items-center justify-center text-sm font-medium text-danger dark:text-danger-500 md:justify-start">
    <img src="{{Storage::url($point->pointCategory->uploaded_file)}}" class="w-6 mr-1"
         alt="{{ Purifier::clean($point->title) }}" loading="lazy"/>
    {{ $point->source_type }}
</div>

and image and category text are on the same line, as I need.
But if point has filled "source_url" field I need to use a tag with href and I do it as:
<div
    class="mb-2 mt-2 flex items-center justify-center text-sm font-medium text-danger dark:text-danger-500 md:justify-start whitespace-nowrap">
    @if(!empty($point->source_url))
        <a href="{{ $point->source_url }}" target="_blank" style="display: inline" >
    @endif
    <img src="{{Storage::url($point->pointCategory->uploaded_file)}}" class="w-6 mr-1"
         alt="{{ Purifier::clean($point->title) }}" loading="lazy"/>
        {{ $point->pointCategory->name }}
    @if(!empty($point->source_url))
        </a>
    @endif
</div>

but in this case image and category text are on the same line and I did not find how to remove this line breaker?
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.4",


From Tailwind's CSS preflight (i.e. reset) <img> elements have display: block. This causes the line break.
In the first example, the line break is not observed due to the parent horizontal flex layout. However, when wrapped in with another HTML element – the <a> element in this case – the <img> is no longer in a flex layout.
To have the <img> display inline, you could consider applying display: inline, display: inline-block, display: inline-flex or display: inline-table via the appropriate class name:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="mb-2 mt-2 flex items-center justify-center text-sm font-medium text-danger dark:text-danger-500 md:justify-start whitespace-nowrap">
  <a href="{{ $point->source_url }}" target="_blank" style="display: inline">
    <img
      src="https://picsum.photos/24/24"
      class="w-6 mr-1 inline"
      alt="{{ Purifier::clean($point->title) }}"
      loading="lazy"
    />
    $point->pointCategory->name
  </a>
</div>



You could also make the <a> element a horizontal flex layout:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="mb-2 mt-2 flex items-center justify-center text-sm font-medium text-danger dark:text-danger-500 md:justify-start whitespace-nowrap">
  <a href="{{ $point->source_url }}" target="_blank" class="flex">
    <img
      src="https://picsum.photos/24/24"
      class="w-6 mr-1"
      alt="{{ Purifier::clean($point->title) }}"
      loading="lazy"
    />
    $point->pointCategory->name
  </a>
</div>



